# Why isn't the rest of my if-else branch executing?

Tags: java, if-statement, multidimensional-array

So I posted this program last night, and still being the OOP padawan that I am, I'm confused as to why the rest of my `if-else` in my method won't execute. I ran the de-bugger and it only ever looks at my `if` and never the `if-else`'s, before executing my return statement. This results in my output not changing as it is supposed to do. Here is the mentioned method:

```
public String getBadge(int requestedStat) {
        String badgeOutput = "";
        if (requestedStat >= 0 && requestedStat <=9) {
            for (int i = 0; i < badgeRanks.length-5; i++) {
                if (gamerActions[requestedStat] >= badgePoints[requestedStat][i]
                        && gamerActions[requestedStat] < badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 1]) {
                    badgeOutput = badgeTitles[requestedStat] + badgeRanks[i];
                } else if (gamerActions[requestedStat] >= badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 1]
                        && gamerActions[requestedStat] < badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 2]) {
                    badgeOutput = badgeTitles[requestedStat] + badgeRanks[i + 1];
                } else if (gamerActions[requestedStat] >= badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 2]
                        && gamerActions[requestedStat] < badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 3]) {
                    badgeOutput = badgeTitles[requestedStat] + badgeRanks[i+2];
                } else if (gamerActions[requestedStat] >= badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 3]
                        && gamerActions[requestedStat] < badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 4]) {
                    badgeOutput = badgeTitles[requestedStat] + badgeRanks[i+3];
                } else if (gamerActions[requestedStat] >= badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 4]
                        && gamerActions[requestedStat] < badgePoints[requestedStat][i + 5]) {
                    badgeOutput = badgeTitles[requestedStat] + badgeRanks[i+4];
                } else {
                    badgeOutput = badgeTitles[requestedStat] + badgeRanks[i+5];
                }
            } 
        } else {
            badgeOutput = "No Badges Available";
        }
        return badgeOutput;
    }
```

I know my design probably isn't the most slick way to do it, that's what I got. What am I doing wrong?
Also here is the other post with the entirety of the other classes: [Difficulty navigating 2d String array that correlates to another 2d int array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27285756/difficulty-navigating-2d-string-array-that-correlates-to-another-2d-int-array)

Comment: can you clarify? Your code is something like if, loop, if/else.  Which if isn't firing?

Comment: Well, if `badgeRanks.length < 5`, the loop would never be entered.

Comment: Voting to close as "Questions seeking debugging help ('**why isn't this code working?**') must include the desired behavior, a *specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)." In your particular case, the biggest problems are: (1) your example is neither minimal nor complete; and (2) it's not clear, at least to me, what behavior you *want*.

Comment: Add System.out.println calls to dump the relevant variables, then check them.

Comment: The first if is the one that executes, the others do not. I expect them to because my test driver is updating random values in `gamerActions[]`. And what I want is for each branch to compare the value at the given index to a set value at the given index of `badgePoints[][]`, and then update the string accordingly.

Comment: What are the values of: requestedStat, badgeRanks(length) and badgeOutput? Can you be more specific in the values you are seeing in the debugger? Otherwise, it's hard to decipher what's going on.

Comment: Sure. requestedStat at the moment is just zero (just a value I'm using to test with) badgeRanks(length) is 5 and the local String is empty until I update it in the if-else branch(on paper it makes sense to me)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An if statement, an else if stattement, and an else statement should cover different, non-overlapping conditions that are possible in your code.

For example:

```
class IfElseDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int testscore = 76;
        char grade;

        if (testscore >= 90) {
            grade = 'A';
        } else if (testscore >= 80) {
            grade = 'B';
        } else if (testscore >= 70) {
            grade = 'C';
        } else if (testscore >= 60) {
            grade = 'D';
        } else {
            grade = 'F';
        }
        System.out.println("Grade = " + grade);
    }
}
```

It's hard to tell without your full program, but it seems like your else statements overlap your if statement. Since the if statement is satisfied, the program does not need to consider the else if's.

From https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html

Comment: I got a 403 on that link but, just to clarify. Are you saying that since my conditionals overlap they never get to execute, because the first statement is satisfied always? Also, thanks for your help on both my posts :)

Comment: Try this one: docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html And yes, basically. Since the "if" is satisfied, the program does not need to look at the else. You are most welcome!